# getting dynamic form element id in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

In the app, Users make post and also make comment on each post submitted.

Each post has a form beneath it for comment and each comment form has the unique id of the post appended to the form name, fields within the forms as well.

I've able to get all post sent to the server via ajax but getting the form values and parameter to send each comment made on each post is being really tough.

The challenge:

1. Getting the formId and also the fieldsId in the form ( via : document.getElementById(unknownUniqueId).value) through which a user is trying to make a comment and processing it via the ajax function that is meant to send them to the php script

The line where the commennt form is created:

```
allPostDivBox = allPostDivBox + '<div class="show_comment_formbox"><form id="formPostComment" onSubmit="return blockCommentSubmit();"><input type="text" id="post_comment' + getPostId + '" name="post_comment' + getPostId + '" maxlength="150" /><input class="comment_btn" type="button" name="comment_submit" value="Post Comment" onClick="javascript:sendCommentFunc();" /> <input type="hidden" id="commenter_mid" name="commenter_mid" value="1" /> <input type="hidden" id="get_post_id' + getPostId + '" name="get_post_id" value="' + getPostId + '" /> <div class="clear"></div></form></div>';
```

The complete Javascript function to display the posts, comments and also create the comment form:

```
// Receives response from server for all post and comment
function statusPostReceivedHandler(){
   if (getStatusPost.readyState == 4){
      if (getStatusPost.status == 200){

         var post_holder_div = document.getElementById('status_update_msg_area');
         post_holder_div.innerHTML = '';

         var allPostDivBox;

         var xmldoc = getStatusPost.responseXML;
         var postNode = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("post");
         for(i = 0; i < postNode.length; i++){

            var postNodeId = postNode[i];

            allPostDivBox = '<div class="status_post_unit">';
            allPostDivBox = allPostDivBox + '<a href="user_view_user_bio.php?getmid=' + postNode[i].getAttribute("poster_mid") + '" rel="facebox[]"><img src="user_pic/'+postNode[i].getAttribute("poster_pix")+'" width="30" height="30" /></a>';
            allPostDivBox = allPostDivBox + '<h3><a href="user_view_user_bio.php?getmid=' + postNode[i].getAttribute("poster_mid") + '" rel="facebox[]">' + postNode[i].getAttribute("poster_name") + '</a></h3>';                  
            allPostDivBox = allPostDivBox + '<div><span>' + postNode[i].getAttribute("poster_acctype") + '</span> | <em>' + postNode[i].getAttribute("post_time") + '</em></div>';
            allPostDivBox = allPostDivBox + '<div>' + postNode[i].getAttribute("post_msg") + '</div>';

            if(postNode[i].getAttribute("post_img") != 'no_img'){
               allPostDivBox = allPostDivBox + '<span><a href="user_view_image.php?post&amp;imid=' + postNode[i].getAttribute("post_id") + '" rel="facebox[]"><img src="img_upload/' + postNode[i].getAttribute("post_img") + '" width="100" height="60" /></a></span>';    
            }

            allPostDivBox = allPostDivBox + '<div class="clear"></div>';

            var getPostId = postNode[i].getAttribute("post_id");

            allPostDivBox = allPostDivBox + '<div class="show_comment_formbox"><form id="formPostComment" onSubmit="return blockCommentSubmit();"><input type="text" id="post_comment' + getPostId + '" name="post_comment' + getPostId + '" maxlength="150" /><input class="comment_btn" type="button" name="comment_submit" value="Post Comment" onClick="javascript:sendCommentFunc();" /> <input type="hidden" id="commenter_mid" name="commenter_mid" value="1" /> <input type="hidden" id="get_post_id' + getPostId + '" name="get_post_id" value="' + getPostId + '" /> <div class="clear"></div></form></div>';

            // START: All comments for post
            allPostDivBox = allPostDivBox + '<div class="status_post_comment_area">';

            var commentNode = postNodeId.getElementsByTagName("comment");
            for(n = 0; n < commentNode.length; n++){
               allPostDivBox = allPostDivBox + '<div class="status_post_comment_unit">';
               allPostDivBox = allPostDivBox + '<div><strong><a href="user_view_user_bio.php?getmid=' + commentNode[n].getAttribute("com_mid") + '" rel="facebox[]">' + commentNode[n].getAttribute("com_name") + '</a></strong></div>';    
               allPostDivBox = allPostDivBox + '<div><span>' + commentNode[n].getAttribute("com_acctype") + '</span> | <em>' + commentNode[n].getAttribute("com_time") + '</em></div>';
               allPostDivBox = allPostDivBox + '<div>' + commentNode[n].getAttribute("com_msg") + '</div>';
               allPostDivBox = allPostDivBox + '</div>';
            }

            allPostDivBox = allPostDivBox + '</div>';
            // END: All comments for post

            allPostDivBox = allPostDivBox + '</div>'

            post_holder_div.innerHTML += allPostDivBox;
         }              

         mTimer = setTimeout('getStatusPostFunc();',30000); //Refresh our post area in 30 seconds           
      }
   }
}
```

Javascript function which is meant to fetch and send the current submitted comment:

```
//Add a comment to the server
function sendCommentFunc() {
   if(document.getElementById('post_comment').value == '') {
   alert("You have not typed or entered a comment");
   return;
}

var comment = document.getElementById('post_comment').value;
var post_id =  document.getElementById('get_post_id').value;
var commenter_mid =  document.getElementById('commenter_mid').value;

var postDataString = 'comment=' + comment + '&post_id=' + post_id + '&commenter_mid=' + commenter_mid;

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url:'inc/status_post_processor.php?send_comment',
   data: postCommentDataString,

   success: function(data){
      document.getElementById('post_comment').value = '';
      // Refresh oour page after sending comment to the server  
      getStatusPostFunc();
   }
});

}
```

Being on this for about 2 days and i'm just stucked. Would be very grateful getting help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the post id on the comment button with a data attribute.

```
'<input ... name="comment_submit" data-id="' + getPostId + '"
  onclick="sendCommentFunc(this)" />'
```

`this` will be the input button element. Now you have access to the element without needing its `id`. But you can still get the post id with the `data-id` attribute.

```
function sendCommentFunc(button) {
    var postId = button.getAttribute("data-id");

    ...
}
```

**Edit:**

After thinking about this a bit more, you don't even need the `data-id`.

```
'<input ... onclick="sendCommentFunc(' + getPostId + ')" />'

function sendCommentFunc(id) {
    var postId = id;
    ...
}
```

Will also get you the id in `sendCommentFunc` but you don't have the reference to the button.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. it worked. Was able to get to postID. I'm sorry i could not respond earlier, got caught up with some things offline. I'm aware this was not part of the question as it didnt occur to me & it does not stop me from ticking your answer correctly cos you've helped solved the core question. But while trying to run the script i realized i'm unable to get the commenterId into the function above via php cos the function is not inline but within an external script. You have any idea how to get a php variable into an external linked javascript?.. Once again, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Oh never mind. I've being able to get my php variable into the js file... Thanks a million for your help...